# Binding Window.Title to Application method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm doing the following in `Window.Loaded` event. Is there a way to do the same through XAML instead, using `{Binding}` or something?

```
this.Title = Application.ResourceAssembly.GetName().Name;
```

I tried the following and a few variations of it, but they don't appear to work:

```
Title="{Binding Source=Application.ResourceAssembly, Path=GetName}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You CAN bind to a method. However, the effort of implementing this is exaggerated in comparison to binding to a property that wraps the method call.
A documentation and guide, how to bind to a method, can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This is nice, but as you said requires more effort than it is worth. I'd just live with the `Loaded` event I guess, unless someone comes up with a nice compact XAML-only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a Property in your Window as

```
public string AppName
{
     get
     {
         return Application.ResourceAssembly.GetName().Name;
     }
}
```

and Bind that property with the `Title`.

```
Title="{Binding AppName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose. One would want to do these simple things either through XAML or C#, not both. If I had to write C# code after all binding stuff, why not live with what I already have.

Comment: Yes i agree to you, Its just a simple way and it was not recommended for your case.. what Herdo linked was suits for you..